# EJB 3 | Entities with webservices

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee

I want to access a inventory system which is accessible through webservice, What is the best way to integrate, I thought of directly expose the entity facade as a web service using `@WebSerive` it's possible but don't know whether it's a good approach or not, need some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you need to do: access a web service or expose something as a web service? It's not clear.

Comment: I want to implement a webservice in order to access the inventory system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could eventually define the methods to be exposed in the same class (or maybe create a wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to **consume** a web service i.e. to implement a web service **client**. My recommendation would be to use JAX-WS for this. See :

- [A Simple JAX-WS Client](http://72.5.124.55/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html#bnayx) in the Java EE 5 Tutorial
- [Developing JAX-WS Web Service Clients](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html)